# Showing that $\sin(p\theta) \leq \sin(\theta)$ for $(p, \theta)\in (0,1)\times [0, \pi/2]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I was wondering how I could show that $\sin(p\theta) \leq \sin(\theta)$ when $0 < p < 1$ and $0\leq \theta \leq \pi/2$. This feels almost obvious since $\sin(\theta)$ is strictly increasing on the chosen interval so that $\sin(p\theta)$ must be "behind" $\sin(\theta)$. But as you might agree, this is a bit handwavy approach. One can always take enough derivatives on both sides to get arbitrary small factor of $p^n$ to the LHS, but I am not sure how this is helpful.

Comment: You are almost there. $0 \le p\theta \le \theta \le \pi/2$ and the sine function is increasing on $[0, \pi/2]$.

Comment: Ah, like I said, almost obvious! Thanks!